# Stream youtube-dl output to S3 using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-dl

### Background:

I'm on Laravel 5.3

I'm downloading a YouTube video using `youtube-dl`, using `Symfony` `Process`:

```
$command = '/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o '.$new_file_path.' '.$youtube_id;
$process = new Process($command);
$process->setTimeout(null);
$process->run();
```

After the `Process` runs, I have the downloaded file in the expected location. Now I can to store it to S3 as follows:

```
\Storage::disk('s3')->putFile($s3_location, new File($new_file_path));
```

### Problem

As you can see, I'm downloading the file to local storage, and then uploading to S3. It would be really great if I could write directly to S3. Especially because both components supports streaming - Process class can stream the output, and S3 Storage can store stream, as follows:

```
// Process class supports streamed output
// https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

// note the '-' after '-o' parameter - it asks youtube-dl to give a stream output, which can be piped in a shell
$process = new Process('/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o - '.$youtube_id;);
$process->start();

foreach ($process as $type => $data) {
    if ($process::OUT === $type) {
        echo "\nRead from stdout: ".$data;
    } else { // $process::ERR === $type
        echo "\nRead from stderr: ".$data;
    }
}
```

And,

```
// S3 Storage supports streams
// https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#storing-files
Storage::put('file.jpg', $resource);
```

My question is - is there a way to wrap the streamed output of `Process` class as a Resource/Stream object, and pass it to S3 Storage?

Comment: You can store file in your memory but you can ask ask youtube server to send your stream to s3, you can't do this in non threading php, you will need multi threaded enable to fetch youtube stream while uploading to s3, still your server must download and upload.

Comment: Can you expand on the "ask youtube server to send your stream to s3" part please?

Comment: When you are uploading to s3, you are doing the handshake from your server IP address, stream must originate from your IP, are you looking for a way to avoid storing the file your HDD/memory?

Comment: Using a stream in memory to act as a buffer, is what I'm looking for. Without writing to HDD.

Comment: Are you using Linux server? how much memory can you allocate for this and what maximum file size you want to transfer at one go? You could quickly run out of memory.

Comment: I'm using a Linux server. If we can use streams correctly, memory will not be an issue, as the buffer can get stored on S3 continuously. File size can go upto multiple GBs.

Answer (score 0):

Correction: The script actually upload all chunks as they become available since `file_get_contents` will continue to reach `EOF`

You need to make sure there is enough memory available since the script doesn't handle total size of available memory versus total video size.

Please note I didn't actually test this since I don't have s3 account, please let me know if there is any issue to correct the answer.

```php
// create ramdrive
// bash $ mkdir /mnt/ram_disk
// bash $ mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m new_ram_disk /mnt/ram_disk

$array_of_youtube_ids = ['abc001', 'abc002' , 'abc003'];
$storage_path = '/mnt/ram_disk/';



// start all downloads
$index = 0;
foreach ($array_of_youtube_ids as $id){

    $youtube_dls$index] = new YouTubeDlAsync($storage_path.$id, $id);
    $youtube_dls[$index]->start();
    $index ++;
}


// upload all downloads
$index = 0;
foreach ($array_of_youtube_ids as $id){

    $s3uploads[$index] = new UploadToS3($storage_path.$id, $resource);
    $s3uploads[$index]->start();

    $index ++;
}

// Wait for all downloads to finish
foreach ($youtube_dls as $youtube_dl)
    $youtube_dl->join();

// Wait for all uploads to finish
foreach ($s3uploads as $s3upload)
    $s3upload->join();

class YouTubeDlAsync extends Thread {

    public function __construct($new_file_path, $youtube_id) {
        $command = '/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o '.$new_file_path.' '.$youtube_id;
        exec($command);
    }
}

class UploadToS3 extends Thread {

    public function __construct($new_file_path, $resource) {
        Storage::put(file_get_contents('file.jpg'), $resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is another version of 'store to disk and then upload to S3' - I'm specifically looking to avoid disk storage (even ram-disk), because, as you rightly mention in the first part of the answer, we'll need to watch out for HD and even 4K videos.

Comment: correction: The script actually upload all chunks as they become available since `file_get_contents` will continue to reach `EOF`